# Raspberry Pi 2 b Start and Stop a python with push switch GPIO 24 and Groung

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, gpio

Im trying to build a door intercom system using Twinkle on Raspberry Pi and Asterisk, I now have my raspberry GPIO PIN 10 and ground with a push switch and I need help with a script that it will STOP/START this Python code when switch is push. thanks a lot in advance.

botton.py

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess, os
import signal

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO_switch = 24 # select pin to connect button
GPIO.setup(GPIO_switch, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

try:

run = 0
while True:
    if GPIO.input(GPIO_switch)==0 and run == 0:
        rpistr = "python3 /home/pi/call.py"
        p=subprocess.Popen(rpistr, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        run=1
        while GPIO.input(GPIO_switch)==0:
            time.sleep(0.01)
    if GPIO.input(GPIO_switch)==0 and run == 1:
        run = 0
        os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
        while GPIO.input(GPIO_switch)==0:
            time.sleep(0.01)


except KeyboardInterrupt:

GPIO.cleanup()
```

call.py

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["twinkle", "-c"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)

for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''):
print line
if (line.find("registration succeeded") > 0):
    proc.stdin.write("call 1000\n")
if (line.find("far end answered call") > 0):
    proc.stdin.write("bye\n")
    proc.stdin.write("quit\n")
proc.communicate()
```

I need help with a script to run at boot that it will wait for the push switch to be press and then start and stop the script on the call.py file

Comment: What's your *specific* question?

Comment: I need a script to run at boot that it will wait for the push switch to be press and then start and stop the script on the call.py file

Comment: Unluckily SO is not a website where you can request coding work from others. You will have to try to solve the problem on your own first and ask a specific question if you get stuck. So far there is nothing related to GPIO in your code.

Comment: Just added the GPIO CODE